# Changing string names from a list

Tags: php, arrays, string, rename

**Doing this in PHP**

I have users input an abbreviation for a city, that gets saved as a string, for example:

`ANA` 
`BOS`
`VAN`

**These stand for:** 
 `Anaheim` 
 `Boston` 
 `Vancouver`

I want it so that when I get the input/string, it changes the string name to it's **full name**.

`ANA` -> `Anaheim` 
`BOS` -> `Boston` 
`VAN` -> `Vancouver`

What is the best way to go about this? Thank you all, greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best way to go about this is first to tell us what language you are using.

Comment: Sorry. I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update:** fixed, so there is no "undefined index" - notice in case you got such a low `error_reporting`level set:

```
$names["ANA"] = "Anaheim";
$names["BOS"] = "Boston";
$names["VAN"] = "Vancouver";

function getFullName($input, $names)
{
    //turning all input into upper case letters:
    $input = strtoupper($input);

    //making sure input is maximum 3 characters long:
    $input = substr($input, 0, 3);

    if(!array_key_exists($input, $names))
    {
        return "*ERROR: Unknown City Abbreviation*";
    }
    else
    {
        return $names[$input];
    }
}

//usage:
$user_input = "bos";
echo getFullName($user_input, $names);
```

Comment: @shock_gone_wild no, it returns `NULL` in case the index does not exist.

Comment: AND produces an undefined index notice ( sorry not an error ) I just tested it

Comment: @shock_gone_wild yeah - ok. a notice...  ok.

Answer (score 1):

Peut22's answer ist working, but i think it is better to store the pairs in an array to be more eaily maintainable. You could also get this array from a database or config file.

```
 $names = array(
    "ANA" => "Anaheim",
    "BOS" => "Boston",
    "VAN" => "Vancouver",
);

if(array_key_exists((string)$userinput, $names)) {
    echo $names[$userinput];
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be much better to use a function here? or do you need to use this code everytime you want to translate a city abbreviation in your code? and what about people writing in lower case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would get a good result by using a switch, which returns the full name if you happend to get an abbreviation, of the full input string if the name is not recognized.

An example in pseudo code would be:

`Switch string
case "ANA" : string = "Anaheim"
case "BOS" : string = "boston"
end`

EDIT: if you're using php, the code would then look like :

```
switch ($i) {
case "ANA":
    $i="anaheim"
    break;
case "BOS":
    $i="boston"
    break;
```

}

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: That's almost correct... Your php code would produce undefined constant notices. You should put the switch cases in '' like switch 'ANA' :

Comment: this is very hard to maintain and extend imho. imagine you get the abbreviaton - name pairs from a database, then it would be practically impossible to use your code.

Comment: @low_rents This algorythm is indeed not  optimised for big php database, but the question was firstly asked without any language specification (why i explained in pseudo code), so the switch seemed reasonnable, and it is still pretty simple to implement.